# avoid Passing Row[id] in URL parameter and index value to another page in web using Php OR javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

how can pass data value to another page without Using

```
<a href="viewproduct.php?p_id=<?php echo $row['id']; >"></a>
```

URL parameter/indexed 
give me some ideas to learn new on making web app

Comment: Use a post request and you can almost send as much data as you want.

Comment: https://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests